# Lightbox and iframe fullscreen

Tags: html

when I'm using iframe to embed gallery into external site, lightbox loads only inside iframe. Example, 640x800px frame.

Is it possible to force it outsite of iframe, to go fullscreen? Like it's with video players.

I'm using Foobox.

Comment: adjust the light box size as per your requirement

Comment: at the moment where the domain of the iframe and the page that contains the iframe is different, there is not possibility to do that. the lightbox is then limited to the area of the iframe.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with HTML5 - see [example](http://johndyer.name/native-fullscreen-javascript-api-plus-jquery-plugin/), [JS Bin with iframe example](http://jsbin.com/aminut/1) and [documentation here](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Gecko%3aFullScreenAPI).

Comment: @user2164609 if you find it to be the correct answer to your question, please consider to [accept it as an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work#answer-5235)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a div instead of an iframe.

```
HTML
<div id="gallery">
The gallery
</div>

CSS
#gallery {
// your css
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Only I would like to embed gallery in other people websites, so i won't be able to modify their css. My goal is to give simple <iframe> or something similar if possible and nothing more.